# linkedlist using javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing linkedlist datastructure using javascript. I have issue with inserting new node in a particular position. I have following code.

```
var node3 = {
    data: 4,
    next: null
},
node2 = {
    data: 3,
    next: node3
},
node1 = {
    data: 1,
    next: node2
},
newNode = {
    data: 2,
    next: null
},
head = node1, current = head, pos = 3, i = 1, prev;

while (current.next) {
    if (pos === i) {
        prev.next = newNode;
        newNode.next = current;
        break;
    }
    prev = current;
    i++;
    current = current.next;
}
```

I am creating 3 nodes initially and finally a `newNode`. I want to insert this `newNode` at position 3 i.e. `pos = 3` which means the end of the list. My above code inserts nodes to other places but it does not at the end. **Why and how can I solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over node3, `current.next == null`, so the loop doesn't execute, so you'll need to come up with another condition for your loop.

Also you should use `break` instead of `return` since you're not in a function.

Comment: Could you add sample example of another condition?

Comment: You could try change it to `current.next || prev.next` instead. The difference it will make is when `current.next` fails and `previous.next` is true which would be at an end node.

Comment: Where could I add `current.next || prev.next`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try dynamic creation of linked list like this.

```
var Linkedlist = function() {
this.head = null;
this.tail = null;
```

};

```
function createNode( val ) {
var node = {};
node[ "key" ] = val;
node[ "prev" ] = null;
node[ "next" ] = null;
return node;
```

}

```
Linkedlist.prototype.insert = function( val ) {
if ( this.head === null ) {
    this.head = createNode( val );
    this.tail = createNode( val );
} else {
    var newNode = createNode( val );
    newNode[ "next" ] = this.head;
    newNode[ "prev" ] = null;
    this.head[ "prev" ] = newNode;
    this.head = newNode;
}
console.log(this);
```

};

```
Linkedlist.prototype.search = function( val ) {
var node = this.head;
while ( node[ "key"] != val ) {
    node = node[ "next" ];
    if ( node === null ) {
        break;
    }
}
return node;
```

};

```
Linkedlist.prototype.remove =  function( val ) {
var node = this.search(val);
if ( node != null ) {
    if ( node[ "next" ] === null && node[ "prev" ] === null ) {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    } else {
        if ( node[ "key"] === this.head[ "key" ] ) {
            this.head = node[ "next" ];
            this.head[ "prev" ] = null;
        } else if ( node[ "key"] === this.tail[ "key" ]) {
            this.tail = node[ "prev" ];
            this.tail[ "next" ] = null;
        } else {
            node[ "prev" ][ "next" ] = node[ "next" ];
            node[ "next" ][ "prev" ] = node[ "prev" ];
        }
    }
    console.log( this );
} else {
    console.log("key doesnt exist");
}
```

};

```
Linkedlist.prototype.largest = function() {
var node = this.head;
var largest = this.head;
while ( node[ "next"] !== null ) {
    if ( node[ "key"] > largest[ "key" ] ) {
        largest = node;
    }
    node = node[ "next" ];
}
return largest;
```

};

Instantiation of this can be done as shown below.

```
linkedlist = new Linkedlist();
linkedlist.insert(1);
linkedlist.insert(2);
linkedlist.insert(3);
linkedlist.insert(4);
linkedlist.remove(2);
linkedlist.largest();
```

Answer (score 0):

With LinkedList, insert at position is not a common practice as LinkedLists don't maintain position for each node, rather it maintains links between nodes. Usually we want to insert before/after a node. More commonly, we want to insert at the end of the list. Below is code to insertAfter a sourceNode

```
this.insertAfter = function(sourceNode, node) {
    var curNode = head;
    while (curNode != null) {
        if (curNode === sourceNode) {
            curNode.setNext(node.setNext(curNode.getNext()));
            return;
        }
        else curNode = curNode.getNext(); 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With your structure ideally insertAt function would look like:

```
var insertAt = function(head, item, index) {
    var curr = head;
    var count = 0;
    while (curr !== null) {
        if (count === index) {
            var newNode = { data: item, next: curr.next };
            curr.next = newNode;
            break;
        }
        count++;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
};

insertAt(head, 2, 3);
```

Let me know if this works.
Also look at this LinkedList class I have created, `insertAt` function is currently missing, but from this stack question, I am planning to add it in my class as well.
[Class- GitHub](https://github.com/dsinjs/linked-list)
[NPM package - @dsinjs/linked-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/linked-list)
[Complete documentation](https://dsinjs.github.io/linked-list/)

Comment: Ref link-

Class - https://github.com/dsinjs/linked-list  
NPM package -https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/linked-list  
Complete documentation - https://dsinjs.github.io/linked-list/